# Multi query and how to wait up last query an do smth?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js

I have cycle with queries:

```js
angular.forEach(checkeds, function(item, i){
  updateData({id: Math.floor(item.id), prcn: item.value });
});
```

and i need to execute function after last queries:

```js
function updateData(model) {
   clientService.updateOptimizable(model).then(function(response){
     if(lastQuery){
       read(); // maybe like this
     }
  }
}
```

help please i have so much information, promises, $q servise, queues, i'm confused and dunno how to do it properly

Comment: Where is the lastQuery coming from? And the last query is it dependent on the angular.foreach or the updateData function.

Comment: @oseintow, last query dependens on updateData, that is after last executed updateData function to execute read()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

Live example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/sp4fekys/).

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', function($scope, $q, $timeout) {
    $scope.checkeds = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1];

    function updateData(val,ind) {
      //simulate call server-side $http.post that return $promise
      var defered = $q.defer();
      $timeout(function() {
        console.log('executed', val, 'index', ind);
        defered.resolve();
      }, val * 1000);
      // in your case, you need return clientService.updateOptimizable(model);
      return defered.promise;
    }
    $scope.start = function() {
      $scope.promises = [];
      angular.forEach($scope.checkeds, function(item, i) {
        $scope.promises.push(updateData(item, i));
      });
      $q.all($scope.promises).then(function() { // this invoke, then ALL updateData is resolve (finished)
        console.log('ALL executed');
      });
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <form name="testForm">
      <button ng-click="start()">
        start
      </button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: THANK YOU ! <3 you are the Best! = )

Answer (score 0):

```
// let set a flag to monitor our last item in the loop
var flag = false;
angular.forEach(checkeds, function(item, i){
   if(i == checkeds.length - 1){
      flag = true;
      updateData({id: Math.floor(item.id), prcn: item.value });
   }
});


function updateData(model) {
   clientService.updateOptimizable(model).then(function(response){
     // if flag is true then do something
     if(flag == true){
        read(); // maybe like this
     }
   }
}
```